# is it possible to get minimumResultsForSearch from Select2 at runtime

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am just wondering if it is possible to get minimumResultsForSearch from Select2 at runtime.

I need it because I want to check if it is greater than -1, so that I know it has a search box.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('select');

for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {

    if($(elements[i]).**minimumResultsForSearch** == -1)
    {
        $(x).select2('close');
    }
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like Object.keys(x).map(function(k){return x[k]}).indexOf('minimumResultsForSearch')> -1

Comment: please can you explain what this is doing? I am literally brand new to javascript and jQuery

Comment: so it finds specific key which you want to search from "select" element object. In your case it is 'minimumResultsForSearch' consider x = elements

Comment: it seems to always return false